# Capture location through smart capture or form on custom cloud pages in salesforce marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, landing-page, cloudpage, geolocation, smart-capture

I want to capture location of customers via smart capture or custom form. As there is a huge list of locations (city,state), I want to integrate the same with google map  or any other similar database available.

Basically when user type 2 or 3 letter, he/she gets suggestions of their nearest locations in drop down and can choose one of them.

Here's the example (swiggy - an indian food delivery app is using)
https://www.swiggy.com/

I want to use similar functionality in forms or smart capture.

Answer (score 1):

This will be a pure front-end implementation, hence agnostic in terms of whether it is running on Cloud Pages or any other platform. You can use some of the many jQuery plugins out there to accomplish this. A quick Google search came up with e.g. this one:
https://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/